# Group By and aggregate on a calculated column

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

Any suggestions please on how to change this Linq to Entities (VB.Net) query to Group by L2_ID column and aggregate the calculated column diff as Sum for the group.

Thanks

```
From l In Level3s 
Join a In BaseLines On l.L3_ID Equals a.L3_ID 
Order By l.L2_ID 
Select Activity = l.L2_ID, Diff = (a.ACT_DATE.Day - l.ACT_DATE.Day)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try two consecutive queries:

```
Dim q = From l In context.Level3s _
        Join a In contexts.BaseLines On l.L3_ID Equals a.L3_ID _
        Order By l.L2_ID _
        Select Activity = l.L2_ID, Diff = (a.ACT_DATE.Day - l.ACT_DATE.Day)
Dim q1 = From el In q _
         Group By Key = el.Activity Into G = Sum(el.Diff) _
         Select Key, G
```

Comment: Thanks Devart, Yes this works, because a.Act_Date and l.Act_Date exist in the l and a. If I want to have Diff to be calculated via a call to a function that returns the value of Diff as an integer, I get an error: Method 'Int32 Diff(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL. Can you suggest a work around. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post by Julie Lerman: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/calling-udfs-from-entity-framework-not-what-you-might-have-expected/ It explains the reason of the error and describes the Entity SQL solution.